# Why does ADODB.STREAM not work in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, adodb, activexobject

Why doesn't this code work in Internet Explorer 9?

```
function GetFile(FileName) {
    var Contents1=null;
    var Stream;
    Stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Stream.Type = 1 //Binary
    Stream.Open()
    Stream.LoadFromFile(FileName)
    Contents1 = Stream.Read()
    FileSize = Stream.Size
    Stream.Close()
    return Contents1;
}
```

Comment: ADODB.Stream could be disabled - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870669

Comment: enable adodb.stream in regedit but dose not work

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `Stream` stuff in the browser? Are you sure you shouldn't be doing an [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) instead? You can do that to files in the file system too (although you won't get predictable HTTP status codes), if the HTML document you're doing this isn't served over HTTP. Instead of focusing on why `ADODB.Stream` doesn't work in IE9, I'd focus on the problem you're trying to solve and see if there's a another (better) solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Contents1 = Stream.Read(-1); //-1 adReadAll
```